# Transferring ETH from Contract to simple wallet *without MIST and synced blockchain*

Tags: wallets, recovery

I have been trying for weeks to sync the blockchain (it just hangs around block 3798000 - and yes I've deleted the chaindata folder, did geth --fast, etc, etc, etc...).  In other words I cannot get MIST up and running to transfer ETH.

My question is this:  Is there any way to transfer ETH from a contract wallet to a simple wallet?  I know both addresses and have the keystore files and password for Geth/Mist.

Answer (score 1):

I know that services like [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-transaction) have the ability to import the keyfile into the online wallet. You can use it and access your account, if you are OK with using third party services.

Comment: Agreed, however, when adding a contract in MyEtherWallet it asks for the keyfile and the ABI/JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to sync the blockchain with [Parity](https://parity.io/) and run it in GETH mode (parity.exe --geth) and then run Ethereum Wallet.exe.  That allowed me to recover my simple wallet and the ETH in my contract.